# How to cbind or rbind different lengths vectors without repeating the elements of the shorter vectors?

Tags: r, vector

```
cbind(1:2, 1:10)  
     [,1] [,2]  
  [1,]    1    1  
  [2,]    2    2  
  [3,]    1    3  
  [4,]    2    4  
  [5,]    1    5  
  [6,]    2    6  
  [7,]    1    7  
  [8,]    2    8  
  [9,]    1    9  
 [10,]    2   10
```

I want an output like below

```
[,1] [,2]  
[1,] 1 1  
[2,] 2 2  
[3,]   3  
[4,]   4  
[5,]   5  
[6,]   6  
[7,]   7  
[8,]   8  
[9,]   9  
[10,]  10
```

Comment: Yup, this is called recycling and is one of R's base concepts. What other behavior do you want?

Comment: This seems to have been addressed through time also: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-cbind-vectors-of-different-length) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613337/the-simplest-way-to-convert-a-list-with-various-length-vectors-to-a-data-frame-i#answer-33622855)

Answer (score 89):

The trick is to make all your inputs the same length.

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:10
n <- max(length(x), length(y))
length(x) <- n                      
length(y) <- n
```

If you want you output to be an array, then `cbind` works, but you get additional `NA` values to pad out the rectangle.

```
cbind(x, y)
       x  y
 [1,]  1  1
 [2,]  2  2
 [3,] NA  3
 [4,] NA  4
 [5,] NA  5
 [6,] NA  6
 [7,] NA  7
 [8,] NA  8
 [9,] NA  9
[10,] NA 10
```

To get rid of the `NA`s, the output must be a list.

```
Map(function(...) 
   {
      ans <- c(...)
      ans[!is.na(ans)]
   }, as.list(x), as.list(y)
)
[[1]]
[1] 1 1

[[2]]
[1] 2 2

[[3]]
[1] 3

[[4]]
[1] 4

[[5]]
[1] 5

[[6]]
[1] 6

[[7]]
[1] 7

[[8]]
[1] 8

[[9]]
[1] 9

[[10]]
[1] 10
```

EDIT: I swapped `mapply(..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE)` for `Map`.

Comment: You could also do `r[which(!is.na(r))]` assuming that `r` is a row of the matrix.

Comment: length(x) <- n thanks, that was exactly what I was looking for

Comment: If you are just looking to write the file, you can replace the NA with blank by doing x[is.na(x)]<-""

Comment: for some reason when I do cbind(x,y) I get repetitions... how do you add NA instead?

Comment: @Alex If the lengths of all the inputs are the same then there is nothing to repeat.  Did you change the lengths of the vectors like it says in my answer?

Comment: @RichieCotton No I didn't, thanks :) For some reason I just thought you were calculating lengths.

Answer (score 29):

I came across similar problem and I would like to suggest that additional solution that some, I hope, may find useful. The solution is fairly straightforward and makes use of the [**`qpcR`**](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/qpcR/index.html) package and the provided [*`cbind.na`*](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/qpcR/docs/cbind.na) function.

## Example

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:10
dta <- qpcR:::cbind.na(x, y)
```

### Results

```
> head(dta)
      x y
[1,]  1 1
[2,]  2 2
[3,] NA 3
[4,] NA 4
[5,] NA 5
[6,] NA 6
```

## Side comments

Following the [**OP's**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445665/chares) original example, column names can be easily removed:

```
colnames(dta) <- NULL
```

the operation would produce the desired output in full:

```
> head(dta)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    2
[3,]   NA    3
[4,]   NA    4
[5,]   NA    5
[6,]   NA    6
```

Comment: This solution is particularly elegant when working with more than two data sets. Using `do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, ...)` allows to easily `cbind` a list of data.frames of arbitrary length.

Comment: cbind.na does not exist (anymore?) in the package qpcR

Comment: @GreenManXY it is an internal function hence the use of `:::` instead of `::`. It is worth noting that calling internal package functions should be used with caution. From ``?`:::` ``: *It is typically a design mistake to use ::: in your code since the corresponding object has probably been kept internal for a good reason.*

Answer (score 9):

I would like to propose an alternate solution that makes use of the [rowr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rowr/index.html) package and their [cbind.fill](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rowr/versions/1.1.3/topics/cbind.fill) function.

```
> rowr::cbind.fill(1:2,1:10, fill = NA);

   object object
1       1      1
2       2      2
3      NA      3
4      NA      4
5      NA      5
6      NA      6
7      NA      7
8      NA      8
9      NA      9
10     NA     10
```

Or alternatively, to match the OP's desired output:

```
> rowr::cbind.fill(1:2,1:10, fill = '');

   object object
1       1      1
2       2      2
3              3
4              4
5              5
6              6
7              7
8              8
9              9
10            10
```

Comment: rowr was removed from CRAN

Answer (score 4):

Given that some of the solutions above rely on packages that are no longer available, here a helper function that only uses `dplyr.`

```
bind_cols_fill <- function(df_list) {

  max_rows <- map_int(df_list, nrow) %>% max()
  
  map(df_list, function(df) {
    if(nrow(df) == max_rows) return(df)
    first <- names(df)[1] %>% sym()
    df %>% add_row(!!first := rep(NA, max_rows - nrow(df)))
  }) %>% bind_cols()
}
```

Note that this takes a list of data frames, so that it is slightly cumbersome if one only wants to combine two vectors:

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:10
bind_cols_fill(list(tibble(x), tibble(y))
```

Comment: After a long time searching, this was the only response that worked. RowR is not working anymore!

Answer (score 3):

Helper function...

```
bind.pad <- function(l, side="r", len=max(sapply(l,length)))
{
  if (side %in% c("b", "r")) {
    out <- sapply(l, 'length<-', value=len)
  } else {
    out <- sapply(sapply(sapply(l, rev), 'length<-', value=len, simplify=F), rev)}
  if (side %in% c("r", "l")) out <- t(out)
  out
}
```

Examples:

```
> l <- lapply(c(3,2,1,2,3),seq)
> lapply(c("t","l","b","r"), bind.pad, l=l, len=4)
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
[2,]    1   NA   NA   NA    1
[3,]    2    1   NA    1    2
[4,]    3    2    1    2    3

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   NA    1    2    3
[2,]   NA   NA    1    2
[3,]   NA   NA   NA    1
[4,]   NA   NA    1    2
[5,]   NA    1    2    3

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1
[2,]    2    2   NA    2    2
[3,]    3   NA   NA   NA    3
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA

[[4]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    2    3   NA
[2,]    1    2   NA   NA
[3,]    1   NA   NA   NA
[4,]    1    2   NA   NA
[5,]    1    2    3   NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution with no dependencies:

```
my_bind <- function(x, y){
if(length(x = x) > length(x = y)){
    len_diff <- length(x) - length(y)
    y <- c(y, rep(NA, len_diff))
}else if(length(x = x) < length(x = y)){
    len_diff <- length(y) - length(x)
    x <- c(x, rep(NA, len_diff))
}
cbind(x, y)
}
my_bind(x = letters[1:4], y = letters[1:2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using other peoples' ideas here and there, below is my own cbind.fill that:

- outputs a data frame
- works with vectors, data frames and matrices alike
- keeps data frames variables classes
- uses only base functions
- gives you the option of giving custom names to the output data frames
- makes me proud

```
cbind.fill = function(...,names=NA) {
  xlist = list(...)
  y= Reduce(
    function(a,b) {
      if(is.vector(a)) na = length(a)
      if(is.data.frame(a)|is.matrix(a)) na = nrow(a)
      if(is.vector(b)) nb = length(b)
      if(is.data.frame(b)|is.matrix(b)) nb = nrow(b)
      subset(
        merge(
          cbind(cbindfill.id = 1:na, a),
          cbind(cbindfill.id = 1:nb, b),
          all = TRUE,by="cbindfill.id"
        ),
        select = -cbindfill.id
      )}
    ,xlist)
  if(!is.na(names[1])) colnames(y) <- names
  return(y)
  }
```

Long story short, it creates the NA using the `merge` function and bypasses the `merge` function limitation to two items by using the `Reduce` function.

Here is an example to test it:

```
x <- 1:2
y <- 1:5
z <- data.frame(my=letters[1:4],your=as.integer(5:8),his=as.factor(12:15))

> cbind.fill(x,y,z)
   a b   my your  his
1  1 1    a    5   12
2  2 2    b    6   13
3 NA 3    c    7   14
4 NA 4    d    8   15
5 NA 5 <NA>   NA <NA>

> str(cbind.fill(x,y,z))
'data.frame':   5 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ a   : int  1 2 NA NA NA
 $ b   : int  1 2 3 4 5
 $ my  : chr  "a" "b" "c" "d" ...
 $ your: int  5 6 7 8 NA
 $ his : Factor w/ 4 levels "12","13","14",..: 1 2 3 4 NA
```