# Combining (cbind) vectors of different length

Tags: list, r, merge, matrix

I have several vectors of unequal length and I would like to `cbind` them. I've put the vectors into a list and I have tried to combine the using `do.call(cbind, ...)`:

```
nm <- list(1:8, 3:8, 1:5)
do.call(cbind, nm)

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    1
# [2,]    2    4    2
# [3,]    3    5    3
# [4,]    4    6    4
# [5,]    5    7    5
# [6,]    6    8    1
# [7,]    7    3    2
# [8,]    8    4    3
# Warning message:
#   In (function (..., deparse.level = 1)  :
#         number of rows of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 2)
```

As expected, the number of rows in the resulting matrix is the length of the longest vector, and the values of the shorter vectors are recycled to make up for the length.

Instead I'd like to pad the shorter vectors with `NA` values to obtain the same length as the longest vector. I'd like the matrix to look like this:

```
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    3    1
# [2,]    2    4    2
# [3,]    3    5    3
# [4,]    4    6    4
# [5,]    5    7    5
# [6,]    6    8    NA
# [7,]    7    NA   NA
# [8,]    8    NA   NA
```

How can I go about doing this?

Comment: flash of brilliance: nm <- cbind( z1,
   c(z2, rep(NA,length(z1)-length(z2)))
)

Answer (score 35):

You can use indexing, if you index a number beyond the size of the object it returns `NA`. This works for any arbitrary number of rows defined with `foo`:

```
nm <- list(1:8,3:8,1:5)

foo <- 8

sapply(nm, '[', 1:foo)
```

EDIT:

Or in one line using the largest vector as number of rows:

```
sapply(nm, '[', seq(max(sapply(nm,length))))
```

From `R 3.2.0` you may use `lengths` ("get the length of each element of a list") instead of `sapply(nm, length)`:

```
sapply(nm, '[', seq(max(lengths(nm))))
```

Comment: `'['` is the name of the operator `[` which you use in indexing (`foo[1:10]`). See also `?'['`

Comment: The one line solution fails if the first column is shorter than the other two.

Comment: The only answer that keeps column name is from @Ronak Shah using the `rowr` package. Is there an alternative with base R that keeps column names?

Answer (score 8):

You should fill vectors with NA before calling do.call.

```
nm <- list(1:8,3:8,1:5)

max_length <- max(unlist(lapply(nm,length)))
nm_filled <- lapply(nm,function(x) {ans <- rep(NA,length=max_length);
                                    ans[1:length(x)]<- x;
                                    return(ans)})
do.call(cbind,nm_filled)
```

Answer (score 3):

This is a shorter version of Wojciech's solution.

```
nm <- list(1:8,3:8,1:5)
max_length <- max(sapply(nm,length))
sapply(nm, function(x){
    c(x, rep(NA, max_length - length(x)))
})
```

Comment: You are always better off using `vapply` rather than `sapply` because that will guarantee you get the output type that you expect.

Comment: @hadley Could you elaborate on your comment? I don't understand the difference between vapply and sapply transferred to this problem.

Comment: sapply is dangerous to program with because it is not type stable - depending on the length of `nm` you'll get different types

Answer (score 3):

Here is an option using `stri_list2matrix` from `stringi`

```
library(stringi)
out <- stri_list2matrix(nm)
class(out) <- 'numeric'
out
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    1
#[2,]    2    4    2
#[3,]    3    5    3
#[4,]    4    6    4
#[5,]    5    7    5
#[6,]    6    8   NA
#[7,]    7   NA   NA
#[8,]    8   NA   NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party but you could use `cbind.fill` from `rowr` package with `fill = NA`

```
library(rowr)
do.call(cbind.fill, c(nm, fill = NA))

#  object object object
#1      1      3      1
#2      2      4      2
#3      3      5      3
#4      4      6      4
#5      5      7      5
#6      6      8     NA
#7      7     NA     NA
#8      8     NA     NA
```

If you have a named `list` instead and want to maintain the headers you could use `setNames`

```
nm <- list(a = 1:8, b = 3:8, c = 1:5)
setNames(do.call(cbind.fill, c(nm, fill = NA)), names(nm))

#  a  b  c
#1 1  3  1
#2 2  4  2
#3 3  5  3
#4 4  6  4
#5 5  7  5
#6 6  8 NA
#7 7 NA NA
#8 8 NA NA
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to bring all list elements to the same length using `length<-` and then you can use `cbind` to get a matrix.

```
nm <- list(1:8, 3:8, 1:5)

do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, `length<-`, max(lengths(nm))))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    3    1
#[2,]    2    4    2
#[3,]    3    5    3
#[4,]    4    6    4
#[5,]    5    7    5
#[6,]    6    8   NA
#[7,]    7   NA   NA
#[8,]    8   NA   NA
```

---

Benchmark

```
nm <- list(1:8, 3:8, 1:5)

bench::mark(
"[" = sapply(nm, '[', seq(max(lengths(nm)))),
"length<-" = do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, `length<-`, max(lengths(nm)))) )
#  express…¹     min  median itr/s…² mem_a…³ gc/se…⁴ n_itr  n_gc total…⁵ result  
#  <bch:exp> <bch:t> <bch:t>   <dbl> <bch:b>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <bch:t> <list>  
#1 [         36.19µs 40.56µs  24412.      0B    12.2  9995     5 409.4ms <int[…]>
#2 length<-   8.63µs  9.88µs 100367.      0B    20.1  9998     2  99.6ms <int[…]>
```

Using `length<-` is in this case about 4 times faster than `[`.