# Workaround for memory allocation

Tags: r, memory-management

I read many questions here on memory management. So I cleaned up my GB size data and narrowed it down to 32MB (770K rows) and store it on BigQuery now. But when I try to turn it into matrix, `as.data.frame(str_split_fixed(event_list$event_list, ",", max(length(strsplit(event_list$event_list, ",")))))`, I get this error

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 4472.6 Gb

Is there anyway to fix this problem, what am I doing wrong here? Is that I store it on BigQuery or converting it to matrix increases the size?

Comment: Isn't it your str_split that is generating way to much data.
Check if `as.data.frame(event_list)` work first

Comment: What's the length of `event_list$event_list`?  Because you're trying to create a data.frame with that many columns.

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin that part of it it works

Comment: @NathanWerth 700 thousand rows and 10 columns

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but it seems like you have a lot of redundancy going on.  Not sure why you are calling `max(length(etc.` as length returns a single integer.  I think maybe you were going for `lengths` (with the "s").  Also, `strsplit` and `str_split_fixed` are very similar.  You could theoretically get the results of `str_split_fixed` from `strsplit`. If you have to compute something more than once, especially if it is an expensive operation, you should only compute one time and store it in a variable.  Continued...

Comment: I would do something like so: `eventSplit <- strsplit(event_list$event_list, ","); maxLen <- max(lengths(eventSplit));` Then using any of the awesome answers found in [How to convert a list consisting of vector of different lengths to a usable data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201305/4408538), we can get our `data.frame`.  I'll use the `plyr` one here as it is super short (not sure if this is the fatest) `plyr::ldply(eventSplit, rbind)` and Voila!

Comment: And now that I think about it, I bet your problem is the call to `length` instead of `lengths`.  If your list is really large, this would cause `str_split_fixed` to make a huge matrix with every row the length of your list.

Comment: @JosephWood very valid points, I will try your suggestions now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@JosephWood nailed it.  If `event_list` has 700,000 rows, then you're trying to create a `data.frame` with 700,000 rows and 700,000 columns. `strsplit(event_list$event_list, ",")` would be a list of length 700,000, so `length(strsplit(event_list$event_list, ","))` gives a single number: `700000`.  `max` of one number is just that number. You should use `lengths` instead.

So your call to `str_split_fixed` ends up acting like this:

```
str_split_fixed(event_list$event_list, ",", n = 700000)
```

That gives a list of 700,000 elements (length of `event_list$event_list`), each element being a character vector with 700,000 values (`n`).

On my machine, I roughly estimated the necessary memory:

```
format(700000 * object.size(character(700000)), "GB")
# [1] "3650.8 Gb"
```

That's not counting any extra memory required to store those vectors in a `data.frame`.

The solution:

```
split_values <- strsplit(event_list$event_list, ",")
value_counts <- lengths(split_values)
extra_blanks <- lapply(max(value_counts) - value_counts, character)
values_with_blanks <- mapply(split_values, extra_blanks, FUN = c, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
DF <- as.data.frame(values_with_blanks)
```

Comment: Nice illustration... especially the memory estimation. This is something that is far too often overlooked.