# How would one go about converting a list with differing numbers of rows to a dataframe?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tibble

I'm trying to convert a list of data from a series of files into a dataframe. I'm using the tibble package to do so.

```
mydata <- as_tibble(mylist, .name_repair = "universal")
```

This method gives me the following error:

> Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.

I have also tried using dpylr to solve the issue:

```
mydata <- dplyr::bind_rows(mylist)
```

But this also gives me an error:

> Can't recycle `p` (size 38) to match `stim` (size 8).

'p' and 'stim' are both elements in the list.

Finally, I have tried the following:

```
mydata <- rapply(mylist, function(x) paste(x, collapse = "|"), how = "replace")
```

But this just gives me a new list rather than a dataframe.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert a uneven list to a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53684158/convert-a-uneven-list-to-a-data-frame) (or any of the nested linked duplicates within that question) - If not, can you edit your question to specify why those approaches dont work, and provide sample data and desired output? Good luck!

Comment: That seems to have solved it- I feel so silly now. Thank you so much for guiding me to that post! I appreciate it!