# Split by confition and fill with NA

Tags: r

How can I get the second table (table2) from the first one (table1) without using any loops?

```
table1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           x = c("1,2,3"),
           y = c("a,b,c,d"),
           z = c("e,f"))
table1

|x     |y       |z   |
|:-----|:-------|:---|
|1,2,3 |a,b,c,d |e,f |

table2 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
           x = c(1, 2, 3, NA),
           y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"),
           z = c("e", "f", NA, NA))
table2

|  x|y  |z  |
|--:|:--|:--|
|  1|a  |e  |
|  2|b  |f  |
|  3|c  |NA |
| NA|d  |NA |
```

[Tabla 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uyP28.png)

[Tabla 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFnNF.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data

Comment: Screenshots are never a good idea to share data. Firstly because we can't do anything with the data lest we manually type it out. Please provide data in a reproducible and copy&paste-able format using e.g. `dput` (or `dput(head(..., n = 20)` if data is large). Alternatively provide code to generate representative mock-up data. See how to provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my attempt at a solution using base R;

```
x = data.frame(x="1,2,3", y="a,b,c,d", z="e,f", stringsAsFactors = F)

# split each column by the comma
x2 = lapply(x, function(x) strsplit(x, ",")[[1]])

# find the max length of the column
L = max(sapply(x2, length))

# make all the columns equal that length i.e. fill the missing with NA 
x3 = lapply(x2, function(x) { length(x) = L; x })

# cbind them all together and turn into dataframe
x4 = data.frame(do.call(cbind, x3))
```

It is quite long though. I would be interested to see a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the stringr package to achieve this

```r
table1 <- data.frame(stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     x = c("1,2,3"),
                     y = c("a,b,c,d"),
                     z = c("e,f"))

t(stringr::str_split_fixed(table1, pattern = ",", max(stringr::str_count(table1, ","))+1))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] "1"  "a"  "e" 
#> [2,] "2"  "b"  "f" 
#> [3,] "3"  "c"  ""  
#> [4,] ""   "d"  ""
```

Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

To break this down into separate steps

1. Find the max length of the columns by counting the number of commas in each column, finding the largest number and adding 1 (since the number of items will be 1 more than the number of commas).

`max(stringr::str_count(table1, ","))+1`

2. Use str_split_fixed to split each column at the comma, use the maximum number of columns based on the str_count() from the previous step. This will fill extra columns with NA.

`stringr::str_split_fixed(table1, pattern = ",", max(stringr::str_count(table1, ","))+1)`

3. Use t() to transpose the table so that it's in the desired format.

`t(stringr::str_split_fixed(table1, pattern = ",", max(stringr::str_count(table1, ","))+1))`