# Remove NA's by keeping all the populated cells in new columns using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data-wrangling

How can I drop all the elements with missing values but instead of deleting entire columns, create columns with just the populated cells? For example getting from this

```
A   B   C   D
1   NA  2   NA
NA  3   NA  4
NA  5   6   NA
```

(`data1`) in order to create a data-set containing only the populated cells, as this

```
AB  BB 
1   2  
3   4
5   6
```

- Below I have created a small working example to test a solution.

```
># Create example dataset (data1)
>data1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,4,NA,5,6,NA),nrow = 3, byrow = T))
>colnames(data1) <- c("A","B","C","D")
     
>print(data1)
 A  B  C  D
 1 NA  2 NA
 NA  3 NA  4
 NA  5  6 NA

> # Create new dataset?
```

Comment: Would each row of the expected output data frame _always_ have two columns, or could there be more or less than 2?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen , there are any more. 360 in total actually. There also could be more populated cells in one row than another. Say row 1 has  5 and row 2 has 6. This would make the new dataset to have 5 populated elements in the first row and 1 NA and 6 populated cells in the second row.

Comment: 1. Will you always have even number of columns? 2. A column will have exactly one pair to combine always? 3. Do you always combine consecutive columns? If the answer of any of the question is No, can you change your example and give a better example which includes these conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential solution using [akrun's/Valentin's answer from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data).

Let's say the data is

```
data1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(1,NA,2,NA,NA,3,NA,4,NA,5,NA,NA),nrow = 3, byrow = T))
> data1 
  X1 X2 X3 X4
1  1 NA  2 NA
2 NA  3 NA  4
3 NA  5 NA NA
```

Then use

```
df1 <- t(sapply(apply(data1, 1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)]), "length<-", max(lengths(lapply(data1, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])))))
```

to arrive at

```
> df1
     X1 X3
[1,]  1  2
[2,]  3  4
[3,]  5 NA
```