# How can I write a list of different length lists to an Excel worksheet?

Tags: r, excel, list, openxlsx

This code runs just fine
(though obviously you will need your username)
unfortunately all it produces is
"We" "Are" "Not" "Alone" on row 6
Rows 3..5 are empty

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb,sheetName = "options")
```

```
List1 <- list("Boo","yay")
List2 <- list("Sok","mmm", "Woohoo")
List3 <- list("A", "B","C","D","E","F")
List4 <- list("We","Are","Not","Alone")
ListofLists <- list(List1,List2,List3,List4)
filetosave <- "C:/Users/Username/Desktop/mylist.xlsx"
```

```
writeRow <- function(r)
{
  openxlsx::writeData(wb, "options", ListofLists[[r]], startCol = 2, startRow = r+2,  
          colNames = FALSE, rowNames = FALSE)
}
```

```
for (r in length(ListofLists))
{writeRow(r)}
```

```
saveWorkbook(wb, file = filetosave, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Comment: Try `for (r in 1:length(ListofLists))`.

Comment: Alternatively, flatten your list into a tabular format (e.g. data frame) and write as one action.

Comment: Hi @Martin Gal could you propose that as an answer. Yes, I know its a stupid error but it is the solution and its the most economical and closest to the original question. I was specifically not wanting to pad the lists into a data frame. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error was caused by a misinterpretation of `R`s `length()` function.
`length(ListOfList)` returns just the length, in this case `4`. So iterating over `length(ListofLists)` only uses the values of `4`

```r
for (r in length(ListofLists))
{writeRow(r)}
```

To get your desired result, you can use

```r
for (r in 1:length(ListofLists))
{writeRow(r)}
```

instead. To prevent unwanted effects in case of `ListofLists` being empty you should use

```r
for (r in seq_len(ListofLists))
{writeRow(r)}
```

- For an empty list, `seq_len(EmptyList)` returns `integer(0)` and the loop doesn't do anything.
- For a non-empty list, `seq_len(NonEmptyList)` returns `1:length(NonEmptyList)`.

Answer (score 2):

It you can save the entire list at one, i.e, not one element after ther other, here is a possible solution:

```
library(openxlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
addWorksheet(wb,sheetName = "options")
List1 <- list("Boo","yay")
List2 <- list("Sok","mmm", "Woohoo")
List3 <- list("A", "B","C","D","E","F")
List4 <- list("We","Are","Not","Alone")
ListofLists <- list(List1,List2,List3,List4)
filetosave <- "mylist.xlsx"

# put your data in a table-like structure
to_save <- tidyr::unnest_wider(tibble::tibble(ListofLists), col = ListofLists, names_sep = "")
# save it as it is
openxlsx::writeData(wb, "options",to_save, startCol = 2, startRow = 2, colNames = FALSE, rowNames = FALSE)
saveWorkbook(wb, file = filetosave, overwrite = TRUE)
```

I got the idea from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36070406/10264278