# Bind list with unequal columns

Tags: r

After countless SO contributions about binding list of data, I'm embarrased to ask this question. However, I cannot seems to find on SO and come up with the right solution myself.

I have list which looks like this:

```
[[1]]
          223586            <NA> 
       "James J." "Adress xxxxx" 

[[2]]
         12693738           <NA>         <NA> 
     "Oliver M." "Address yyyyy" "Town xxxxx"
```

What I would like to get is: The missing filled with `NA`

```
                          <NA>       <NA>
         James J. Adress xxxxx       NA
         Oliver M. Address yyyyy town xxxx
```

I'm getting the last column (lenght 2) filled with name `(first column entry)` James J. in this case:

```
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, list)

             NA         NA        NA  
         James J. Adress xxxxx   James J.
         Oliver M. Address yyyyy town xxxx
```

EDIT: There is nothing particular about this data. It is more about how to bind unequal length of data in list. There are either `lapply(list, function(x) length(x))` length of 2 or 3 strings.

So I would like to replace the missing `length 2` with `NA` so that the list can be bind.

Comment: So how many items are there in a full list? I'm a little confused by the <NA> in your list data. Can you give some more detail about how the list is formed? Also, will it always be the Town field missing?

Comment: Please post the output from `dput( list )` so we can reconstruct your data easily.

Comment: @Eddie: the <NA> can be easily placed by other name once in dataframe as `colname(datafame) <- c("Column1","Column2","Column3")`. Why the binding doesn't work is because each `[[i]]` list isn't same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question can be found in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-unequal-columns-in-r?rq=1) on the right. If you want to change your list elements so that they are all of the same length, you can do:

```
lst <- list(a = 1:3, b = 1:4, name = c("A", "X"))  #a list for the example

n <- max(unlist(lapply(lst, length)))              #check maximum length

lstnew <- lapply(lst, function(x) {ans <- rep(NA, length=n); 
                                   ans[1:length(x)]<- x; 
                                   return(ans)})   #Add NA for elements shorter than n
```

And then convert your list to whatever you need. Or, much shorter, you could use sapply:

```
sapply(lst,'[',1:n)         #to return a matrix
```

or if you need a data.frame

```
as.data.frame(sapply(lst,'[',1:n))
```

or

```
as.data.frame(lapply(lst,'[',1:n))
```