# The simplest way to convert a list with various length vectors to a data.frame in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, data-science

Here I have a list with different length vectors. And I'd want to get a data.frame. I've seen lots of posts about it in SO (see ref), but none of them are as simple as I expected because this is really a common task in data preprocessing. Thank you.

Here simplest means `as.data.frame(aa)` if it works. So one function from the base package of R will be great. `sapply(aa, "length<-", max(lengths(aa)))` has four functions actually.

An example is shown below.

Input:

```
aa <- list(A=c(1, 3, 4), B=c(3,5,7,7,8))
```

Output:

```
A B
1 3
3 5
4 7
NA 7
NA 8
```

A and B are the colnames of the data.frame.

One answer is `sapply(aa, '[', seq(max(sapply(aa, length))))`, but it's also complex.

ref:

1. [How to convert a list consisting of vector of different lengths to a usable data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201305/how-to-convert-a-list-consisting-of-vector-of-different-lengths-to-a-usable-data)
2. [Combining (cbind) vectors of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-unequal-columns-in-r)

Comment: You can make it compact with `data.frame(lapply(aa, "length<-", max(lengths(aa))))`  It is also faster when compared to `sapply(aa, length)`

Comment: [tag:data-science]???

Comment: @akrun, it's a solution, but not as simple as possible in R.

Comment: @David Arenburg, It's related with data science as data preprocess is always an important part for data science due to the unformatted data.

Comment: You can use `library(stringi); stri_list2matrix(aa)` but the character elements needs to be converted to `numeric` though.  I am not sure whether `simple` means `compact` code for you though.

Comment: @akrun, I think `stri_list2matrix` is a simple answer, though I think there should be a function in the base package in R. In my opinion, `simple` means easy to use and to be understood.

Comment: Well, you can create a function with these tools so that it becomes `simple` for you.

Comment: @akrun, `sapply(aa, "length<-", max(lengths(aa)))` works as well. Here it seems `length<-` means `length(x) <- max(lengths(aa))`?

Comment: Yes, and it is very fast based on some benchmarks done earlier.

Comment: @ZhilongJia, I found the comment of @fdetsch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o#comment71565926_36692363) interesting. Maybe something like `do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, aa)` could be interesting, but is not fully base R though.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We can use

```
data.frame(lapply(aa, "length<-", max(lengths(aa))))
```

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(aa) %>%
    unnest(value)
```

Comment: We don't know what the OP regards as "simple", but `setDT` in place of `data.frame` saves some characters and operations.

Comment: @Frank I agree.  It seems to me that the OP wants `base R` options.

Answer (score 2):

Using tidyverse packages. Place the list in a nested data frame. Extract the `name` for each vector in the list. Unnest the data frame. Give a row index `i` for each element in each vector, spread the data in wide format

```
    aa <- list(A = c(1, 3, 4), B = c(3, 5, 7, 7, 8))
    library(tidyverse)
    data_frame(data = aa) %>% 
        group_by(name = names(data)) %>% 
        unnest() %>%
        mutate(i = row_number()) %>% 
        spread(name, data)
    # A tibble: 5 x 3
          i     A     B
    * <int> <dbl> <dbl>
    1     1     1     3
    2     2     3     5
    3     3     4     7
    4     4    NA     7
    5     5    NA     8
```

Answer (score 1):

Make this function:

```
listToDF <- function(aa){
  sapply(aa, "length<-", max(lengths(aa)))
 }
```

Then use it, simply:

```
listToDF(aa)
```