# Combine matrices of different length and keep column names

Tags: r, cbind, stringi

There is a similar question about combining vectors with different lengths [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-cbind-vectors-of-different-length), but all answers (except [@Ronak Shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5531471/combining-cbind-vectors-of-different-length/53893866#53893866)`s answer) loose the names/colnames.

My problem is that I need to keep the column names, which seems to be possible using the `rowr` package and `cbind.fills`.

I would like to stay in **base-R** or use `stringi` and the output shoud remain a matrix.

Test data:

```
inp <- list(structure(c("1", "2"), .Dim = 2:1, .Dimnames = list(NULL,"D1")), 
            structure(c("3", "4", "5"), .Dim = c(3L, 1L), .Dimnames = list(NULL, "D2")))
```

I know that I could get the column names beforehand and then reassign them after creating the matrix, like:

```
## Using stringi
colnam <- unlist(lapply(inp, colnames))
out <- stri_list2matrix(inp)
colnames(out) <- colnam
out    

## Using base-R
colnam <- unlist(lapply(inp, colnames))
max_length <- max(lengths(inp))
nm_filled <- lapply(inp, function(x) {
  ans <- rep(NA, length = max_length)
  ans[1:length(x)]<- x
  ans
})
out <- do.call(cbind, nm_filled)
colnames(out) <- colnam
out
```

Are there other options that keep the column names?

Comment: In that question it is list of vectors but here you have got list of matrices. Is that intentional ?

Comment: Yes I know, but it is still working with matrices aswell. Yes it could also have multiple columns, not just 2.

Comment: How would different columns be treated? For example, what would be your expected output for `inp` after changing `inp[[1]] <- cbind(inp[[1]], "D3" = 4)` ?

Comment: It should be filled with NA. So this should result in `cbind(inp[[1]], "D3" = c(4,NA))`

Answer (score 2):

Since `stringi` is ok for you to use, you can use the function `stri_list2matrix()`, i.e.

```
setNames(as.data.frame(stringi::stri_list2matrix(inp)), sapply(inp, colnames))
#    D1 D2
#1    1  3
#2    2  4
#3 <NA>  5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly more concise base R variation

```
len <- max(lengths(inp))
nms <- sapply(inp, colnames)
do.call(cbind, setNames(lapply(inp, function(x)
    replace(rep(NA, len), 1:length(x), x)), nms))
#      D1  D2
#[1,] "1" "3"
#[2,] "2" "4"
#[3,] NA  "5"
```

Not sure if this constitutes a sufficiently different solution from what you've already posted. Will remove if deemed too similar.

---

### Update

Or how about a `merge`?

```
Reduce(
    function(x, y) merge(x, y, all = T, by = 0),
    lapply(inp, as.data.frame))[, -1]
#    D1 D2
#1    1  3
#2    2  4
#3 <NA>  5
```

The idea here is to convert the `list` entries to `data.frame`s, <s>then add a `row` number and `merge` by `row`</s> and `merge` by row by setting `by = 0` (thanks @Henrik). Note that this will return a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix`.

Comment: You can replace `sapply(inp, length)` with `lengths(inp)`

Comment: No definitly worth an answer, as it is indeed way more compact than my base-R approach. Unfortunately it is also necessary to get the names first and reassign them.

Comment: @Sotos Ah thanks, I always forget about `lengths`. Made an edit.

Comment: @SeGa I've added an alternative approach using `merge`. The only difference is that it returns a `data.frame` rather than a `matrix`.

Comment: Also nice approach, but yeah I would like to keep the matrix format. I've added it in my question.

Comment: if you specify `by = 0` in `merge` (merge on row names), `lapply(inp, as.data.frame)` is enough.

Comment: @Henrik Nice! I didn't know about the `by = 0` option.

Answer (score 1):

Here is using base:

```
do.call(cbind,
        lapply(inp, function(i){
          x <- data.frame(i, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
          as.matrix( x[ seq(max(lengths(inp))), , drop = FALSE ] ) 
          #if we matrices have more than 1 column use:
          #as.matrix( x[ seq(max(sapply(inp, nrow))), , drop = FALSE ] )
        }
        ))


#    D1  D2 
# 1  "1" "3"
# 2  "2" "4"
# NA NA  "5"
```

The idea is to make all matrices to have the same number of rows. When we subset *dataframe* by index, rows that do not exist will be returned as NA, then we convert back to matrix and *cbind*.