# How to convert a list of uneven vectors into a long-format dataframe, possibly without padding with NA?

Tags: r, list, dataframe, vector

Consider a list `a` of vectors. All vectors have the same type (*i.e.* Date in my case), vectors can have different lenght.

```r
> str(a)
List of 2
 $ item1: Date[1:3], format: "1999-02-06" "1999-10-23" "1999-09-13"
 $ item2: Date[1:2], format: "1999-12-05" "1999-11-30"
```

**How to convert this list in a *long*-dataframe-like structure?** The expected output looks like:

| items | dates |
| --- | --- |
| item1 | 1999-02-06 |
| item1 | 1999-10-23 |
| item1 | 1999-09-13 |
| item2 | 1999-12-05 |
| item2 | 1999-11-30 |

The code to make `a`:

```r
a <- list(item1 = structure(c(10628, 10887, 10847), class = "Date"), 
    item2 = structure(c(10930, 10925), class = "Date"), item3 = structure(c(10764, 
    10671, 10917, 10887), class = "Date"))
```

In this case, "usual" technique involving row/col-wise binding do not work:

```
>   bind_rows(a)
Error:
! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
• Size 2: Column `item2`.
• Size 3: Column `item1`.
ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
>   bind_cols(a)
Error in `bind_cols()`:
! Can't recycle `item1` (size 3) to match `item2` (size 2).
```

I feel this question has already an answer on SO but I might not have used the correct keywords...
Here are some posts I found:

- [Combining (cbind) vectors of different length](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5531471/10264278)
- [How to convert a list consisting of vector of different lengths to a usable data frame in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15201305/10264278)

But they do not answer this question as the output is not in long format and require to padding each shorter vector with `NA`. I could do this and then `pivot_longer()` but maybe there is a way without filling shorter vectors with `NA`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tibble::enframe` with `tidyr::unnest`:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
enframe(a, name = "items", value = "dates") %>%
   unnest(dates)
```

```r
  items dates     
1 item1 1999-02-06
2 item1 1999-10-23
3 item1 1999-09-13
4 item2 1999-12-05
5 item2 1999-11-30
6 item3 1999-06-22
7 item3 1999-03-21
8 item3 1999-11-22
9 item3 1999-10-23
```

Comment: Just perfect, thank you! Even after all this time I have never seen this function being used...