# How to efficiently divide successor by predecessor in each column of a dataframe

Tags: r, performance, dataframe, cbind

I have a `dataframe` `myDF` created like this:

```
a <- 1:4
b <- seq(3, 16, length=4)
myDF <- data.frame(a=a, b=b)
```

which looks like this:

```
  a         b
1 1  3.000000
2 2  7.333333
3 3 11.666667
4 4 16.000000
```

Now I want to divide subsequently predecessor and successor in each column, add the results to the existing dataframe, replace the one missing value in each column by `NA` and add new column names. For the example above, my desired outcome looks like this:

```
  a         b     amod     bmod
1 1  3.000000       NA       NA
2 2  7.333333 2.000000 2.444444
3 3 11.666667 1.500000 1.590909
4 4 16.000000 1.333333 1.371429
```

So, in column `a` 2 is divided by 1, 3 is divided by 2, and 4 is divided by 3 and the results are stored in `amod`.

The way I do it now is like this:

```
divStuff <-function(aCol){

  newCol <- aCol[2:length(aCol)]/aCol[1:length(aCol) - 1]
  newCol <- c(NA, newCol)

  return(newCol)
}
newDF <- data.frame(lapply(myDF, divStuff))
names(newDF) <- paste(names(myDF), "mod", sep="")
endDF <- cbind(myDF, newDF)
```

I wrote a function `divStuff` which does the division and then call `lapply` which applies this function to each column of the data frame.

Now I am wondering whether that is the way to do it or whether there is a smarter way on doing such kind of operations which would e.g. avoid the `cbind` call or does the `cbind` in a way which avoids the line `newCol <- c(NA, newCol)` by adding a `NA` automatically. I did not find a nice way, all solutions for that looks similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `base R`:

```
myDF[,paste0(names(myDF), "mod")] <- sapply(myDF, function(x) c(NA, x[-1]/head(x,-1)))
#  a         b     amod     bmod
#1 1  3.000000       NA       NA
#2 2  7.333333 2.000000 2.444444
#3 3 11.666667 1.500000 1.590909
#4 4 16.000000 1.333333 1.371429
```

Comment: Probably `paste0(names(myDF), "mod")` will be more general

Comment: Excellent, that works fine! I upvote it for now and might accept it later one.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a quick `data.table` version (using the [devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation))

```
library(data.table) ## V 1.9.5
setDT(myDF)[, paste0(names(myDF), "mod") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/shift(x))]
#    a         b     amod     bmod
# 1: 1  3.000000       NA       NA
# 2: 2  7.333333 2.000000 2.444444
# 3: 3 11.666667 1.500000 1.590909
# 4: 4 16.000000 1.333333 1.371429
```

Or similarly with `dplyr` though you may want to play around with the column names (this is due a bug(?) in `mutate_each` when it drops the original columns and doesn't rename the resulting ones when given a single function)

```
library(dplyr)
myDF %>% 
  mutate_each(funs(./lag(.))) %>%
  cbind(myDF, .)
#   a         b        a        b
# 1 1  3.000000       NA       NA
# 2 2  7.333333 2.000000 2.444444
# 3 3 11.666667 1.500000 1.590909
# 4 4 16.000000 1.333333 1.371429
```

Comment: That looks more like I have in mind for such a 'simple' task. I try it once I have updated my R version; with mine I run into dependency issues. But already thanks a lot for the input!

Comment: Works fine as well! The first solution also requires the packages 'magic' which contains the 'shift' function; maybe you can update your post!? Since it is a nice and working solution, I upvote it but will accept Pierre Lafortune's one since it does not require any additional packages.

Comment: If you want to avoud `shift` you can simply do `setDT(myDF)[, paste0(names(myDF), "mod") := lapply(.SD, function(x) x/c(NA, x[-.N]))]`

Comment: Ok, thanks! Could learn a lot from your answer! The comment about 'magic' was more for other people that want to reproduce your result; I found it quickly but others might do not find it.

Comment: To the data.table package but not to 'magic' or do I overlook something?

Comment: To [the devel version on GH](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation)

Comment: OK, now I see; I have indeed version 1.9.4 while you have 1.9.5 - my fault, then it should be fine.