# Making data frames from numeric and character data classes in R

Tags: r, vector

As a background. I have two numeric data values (say age and value) and two character data classes (gender and comms). gender is categorical as male and female while comms is categorical as sms and letter.

I tried creating a data frame as follows:

```
age <- c(mean(age))

value <- c(mean(value))

gender <- c("male", "female")

comms <- c("sms", "letter")

together <- data.frame(age, value, gender, comms)
```

It gives me an error of arguments imply differing number of rows. Please help on how can I create a dataframe for these data classes.

I want to create an output that looks like

```
Age     value    gender    comms
24      500       Male      sms
24      500       Female    letter
24      500       Female    sms
24      500       Male      letter
```

Comment: What is the length of `age` and `value`?

Comment: Both are of length 1

Comment: Can you show us what you want your data frame output to look like?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've edited my original post to answer your question

Comment: Your output doesn't make any sense to me.  Why would you want the first and third rows to be duplicates of each other?

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to accomplish here with that `df` but your code works

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I'm sorry I was not so clear. That is because the age column is only showing the mean of all the ages while the value column is showing the mean of values. The contents of the other columns Gender and Comms are then alternating (in no particular order). I want to put all the values in a data frame before creating another column that will be a reflection of the changing gender and comms

Comment: @Sotos It could work but what then happens in a case whereby the comms is of three or more categories? It doesn't work then or am I missing something?

Comment: You need to clarify that in your question. However, it sounds to me that you need to make your vectors the same length before binding them to a df. Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o

Comment: @Sotos, I just checked the reference you gave. It does not fill up the empty spaces in the data frame with actual contents as I would want R to, it only just forces them to be same length with empty spaces.

Comment: R will recycle shorter vectors _if possible_. Try `data.frame(gender = letters[1:6], val = 1:3)` and `data.frame(gender = letters[1:5], val = 1:3)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, your example is very confusing and it is not clear what you want to do. As I understand it, you could create a `list` of data.frames and use `rbindlist`

```
age <- c(24)

value <- c(400)

gender <- rep_len(c("Male","Female"), length(comms1)) #as suggested by @Jimbou

comms <- c("sms", "letter")

comms1 <- c("sms", "letter", "email", "telephone", "morsecode", "whitedove")

df1 <- data.frame(age, value, gender, comms)
df3 <- data.frame(age, value, gender, comms1)
ls <- list(df1, df3)
rbindlist(ls)

#  age value gender     comms
#1:  24   400   male       sms
#2:  24   400 female    letter
#3:  24   400   male       sms
#4:  24   400 female    letter
#5:  24   400   male     email
#6:  24   400 female telephone
#7:  24   400   male morsecode
#8:  24   400 female whitedove
```

Comment: Thanks so much, just what I needed.

Comment: This approach is only working if the length of the vectors are multiples of each. Otherwise the data.frame function gives an error. To extend the vectors you can use `rep_len(c("Male","Female"), length(your_vector))` while `your_vector` specifies the longest one.

Comment: @Jimbou Great review and extension of the problem, thanks.

Comment: @Sotos, I just checked again and got a message saying I need to have a total of 15 reputation before my check can show. Since I just joined, I don't have the reputation yet.

Comment: by the way, just curious, is the `mean(age)` the same in both male and female, or did you just average all ages?

Comment: @Sotos, I averaged all the ages. Any further insights?