# Matrix of vectors in r with col/row names and unknown length

Tags: r, matrix, vector

I'm trying to create a data structure to store vectors. What I'm looking for is a 3x2 matrix with vectors of different lenght inside.

```
             front        side 
Original  c(dim=221) c(dim =200)
zscore    c(dim=221) c(dim =200)
smoothed  c(dim=221) c(dim =200)
```

I have tried doing:

```
dataset <- array(dim=c(3,2))
rownames(dataset) <- c("original","zscores","smoothed")
colnames(dataset) <- c("front", "side")

dataset["original", "side"] <- myNumericVectorOfLength221
dataset["original", "front"] <- myNumericVectorOfLength200
```

But it throws an error of "not the same size". A three dimensional array like: `dataset <- array(dim=c(3,2,221))` didn't work because of the differences of length and if I create a matrix of vectors like `(dataset["original", "side"] <- list(c(1,2,3)))` I lose the col/rownames.

Is there any solution that fits my idea? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe [this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o)

Comment: You can assign names to elements of alist, wouldn't that suffice?

Comment: Can you explain it a little bit more, please? @LeoP.

Comment: You could try a three dimensional array with the third dimension as large as your biggest vector, and fill the other vectors with NAs, so they all have the same length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a multi-dimensional list, e.g. :

```
# prepare some random vectors with different lengths
myNumericVectorOfLength221 <- rnorm(221)
myNumericVectorOfLength200 <- rnorm(220)

# create a multi dimensional list
dataset <- array(list(),dim=c(3,2))
rownames(dataset) <- c("original","zscores","smoothed")
colnames(dataset) <- c("front", "side")

# fill some cells
dataset[["original", "side"]] <- vec10
dataset[["zscores","front"]] <- vec3

# let's see the whole matrix
> dataset
         front     side      
original NULL      Integer,10
zscores  Integer,3 NULL      
smoothed NULL      NULL

# let's get one of the added vector
> dataset[["original", "side"]]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

Comment: This is a very useful enhancement of my `list`-approach. I didn't even know you could do this. Thanks!

Comment: Great! Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You could save your vectors in a list and name the elements of said list.

Either create one list with all vectors

```
mylist <- list("front_Original" = vector1, "front_zscore" = vector2, ...)
```

or create sublists for your factors

```
mylist2 <- list("front" = list("Original" = vector1, "zscore" = vector2, ...), 
               "side" = list("Original" = vector3, "zscore" = vector4))
```

List elements can be of different classes and dimensions, therefore you would not run into any problems this way. Refering to a list works similarly to a `data.frame`, so you could call a certain vector of `mylist2` with `mylist2$front$Original` or with `mylist2[[1]][[1]]`.

Comment: Ok, I understand you now. The main problem is that I'm using a variable "type" to get the a string like "Original" so I would like to call the array like: dataset[type, "side"]. I have just tried to do the same with 'mylist2$front$type and it doesn't work. Is there anyway to call the list this way? thanks for your help.