# How to get rid of NA's in cbind

Tags: r, xml, cbind

I am parsing XML-TEI file. Following [this explanation for different length](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o) of vectors, I have this script:

```
cat_xmlID <- getNodeSet(doc, "//ns:category/@xml:id", ns)
cat_xmlID

role=unlist(cat_xmlID[27:29])
context=unlist(cat_xmlID[9:25]) 
sphere=unlist(cat_xmlID[4:7])
sex=unlist(cat_xmlID[49:50]) 


n <- max(length(context), length(role), length(sphere), length(sex))
length(context) <-n 
length(role) <-n 
length(sphere) <-n 
length(sex) <-n 
catTab_ObjV=cbind(role, context, sphere, sex)
catTab_ObjV
```

Result:

```
    role          context        sphere      sex        
id "active"      "ritual"       "inside"    "male_Sx"  
id "passive"     "battle"       "outside"   "female_Sx"
id "both_active" "singleCombat" "unknown_S" NA         
   NA            "prayer"       "B_ctx_S"   NA         
   NA            "assembly"     NA          NA         
   NA            "feast"        NA          NA         
   NA            "wedding"      NA          NA         
   NA            "burial"       NA          NA         
   NA            "seduction"    NA          NA         
   NA            "meeting"      NA          NA         
   NA            "complaint"    NA          NA         
   NA            "lawsuit"      NA          NA         
   NA            "threat"       NA          NA         
   NA            "revenge"      NA          NA         
   NA            "visit"        NA          NA         
   NA            "unknown_C"    NA          NA         
   NA            "B_ctx_C"      NA          NA
```

Of course, I have a lot of NAs. I didn't understand the explanation on how to get rid of NAs in the above-mentioned post and in several other posts — none give a relevant explanation for NA for `cbind` function.
I must say I am a beginner in R...

Can you help me?
In advance, thank you.

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: I have added sample data.

Comment: What is your desired output? Is it a rectangular table, if so what do you want instead of NAs? Or is it a ragged array, in which case replace cbind(.....) with list(role = role, context = context,  .....)?

Comment: I want no value at all, so no NA. The goal of this template is to list the attributes of each category (role, context, sphere, sex). So NA means nothing here. It will not to be used for computation, but only to display what I am going to use for my analytical investigation.

Comment: If my answer solved your issue, could you please mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: you cannot (get rid of `NA`s in `cbind()`), because `cbind()` is meant to output a rectangular table (`data.frame` or `matrix`), and those mandate consistent length of all columns. `NA` is the closest you can get to "no value". There is also `NULL`, but `NULL` cannot populate a cell of a table.

It seems a `data.frame` or a `matrix` is not the appropriate data structure here, which could be a ragged array in the form of a list: `list(role = role, context = context, sphere = sphere, sex = sex)`.

But your comment makes it clearer that the real question is about display and nothing else, so *for this particular case only*, since lists are not well suited for clean display, let's keep it a matrix.

So it really depends on *how* you intend to display the data in your final output (LaTeX? HTML? copy-paste from a `print()`?) 
For instance, you could go with a "hacky" replacement of `NA` with empty strings `""` such as: `catTab_ObjV[is.na(catTab_ObjV)] <- ""`

Or use a dedicated package such as `xtable`, which doesn't even require you to "remove" `NA`s:

```
library(xtable)

foo <- c("a", "b", "c")
bar <- c("d", "e", NA)
tab <- cbind(foo, bar)
tab
#      foo bar
# [1,] "a" "d"
# [2,] "b" "e"
# [3,] "c" NA 

print.xtable(xtable(tab), type = "html")
# <!-- html table generated in R 3.3.2 by xtable 1.8-2 package -->
# <!-- Sat Mar 18 11:54:06 2017 -->
# <table border=1>
# <tr> <th>  </th> <th> foo </th> <th> bar </th>  </tr>
# <tr> <td align="right"> 1 </td> <td> a </td> <td> d </td> </tr>
# <tr> <td align="right"> 2 </td> <td> b </td> <td> e </td> </tr>
# <tr> <td align="right"> 3 </td> <td> c </td> <td>  </td> </tr>
# </table>
```

[image: exemple xtable]

Comment: Thanks for your reply and my apologies for my late reply. I want to print on screen, so I use `write.csv2` but still I have the **NA**. I have tried your solution, but it doesn't work, probably because it's made or LateX.

Comment: `write.csv2` has a `na` argument, which defaults to `"NA"`. Use `write.csv2(catTab_ObjV, "path/to/csv", na = "")`

Comment: I follow your example: `write.csv2(catTab_ObjV,file="categories' template of objective variables taxonomy.csv", na = "")`, but still I have the `"NA"`

Comment: How do you open the resulting csv?

Comment: My apologies! I first looked with data global environment of R. But after reading your last question, I have opened it with Excel. It works!! Thanks so much.