# Error in Dataframe : arguments implying different number of arguments

Tags: r, dataframe, outliers, rbind, cbind

my data frame had many outliers in each column / variable. I removed them using Boxplot / IQR cut-off for 75% / 25%. I took out each column and removed outliers from them. Therefore, each column has different number of values in it. Now I want to combine those all NEW variables which does not has any outlier in it to single data frame. I am getting this error in Data frame. How do I solve this problem? Because, I have to perform logistic regression on that NEW data frame. I tried cbind.data.frame and then similar with rbind, but that is not solving the issue.

Here is the code:

```
newdata <- data.frame(finalsbp, mynewT, mynewldl,mynewtypea1, mynewobesity, mynewalcohol, age, famhist)

Error in data.frame(finalsbp, mynewT, mynewldl, mynewtypea1, mynewobesity,  : 

arguments imply differing number of rows: 447, 443, 448, 458, 454, 429, 462
```

P.S. Length of age and famhist is same. i.e. 462

Comment: I would look into using merge() on your data. Please give some code to make a minimum reproducible example, and what your expected output is.

Comment: @RichardLusch

I tried this

    > merge(finalsbp, mynewT, mynewldl,mynewtypea1, mynewobesity, mynewalcohol, age, famhist)


    Error in fix.by(by.x, x) : 'by' must match numbers of columns

Comment: @RichardLuschL I have edited my question, you can check. Need help with my question. If you cannot answer, fine but do not give -1 (especially when I have made changes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing more about your data, you could try to just make each vector the same length like this as indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o).

```
a <- seq(from = 1, to = 10)
b <- seq(15, 30)
c <- seq(2, 10)

length(a) <- n
length(b) <- n
length(c) <- n

newdata <- cbind(a, b, c)
```

This should solve your problem, assuming you want all the blanks to appear as NA at the end of the data frame.

Comment: Thanks. It works. I have added n=500, so the length will be uniform for making a dataframe.