# cbind two dataframes where weekdays match

Tags: r, match, cbind

Before asking, I have searched and read many other questions on stackoverflow and tried the `join`s from `dplyr` package but none gives the result I want.

I have two dfs and want to combine them that first values in `df1$col1` which is `Wed` is matched with first occurrence of `Wed` in `df2$col3` then these two dfs are combined as shown in df3

```
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = c('Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon',
                           'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun',
                           'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat',
                           'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'),
                  col2 = c(102, 101, 100, 107, 91, 80, 80, 68, 65, 69,
                           69, 74, 66, 58, 59, 64, 76, 70, 73, 71, 60))

df2 <- data.frame(col3 = c('Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun',
                           'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 
                           'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 
                           'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon'),
                  col4 = c(107, 91, 70, 73, 71, 80, 80, 58, 59, 64, 68,
                           65, 102, 101, 100, 69, 69, 74, 66, 76, 60))
```

This is what I want to get!

```
df3 <- data.frame(col1 = c('Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue'), 
col2 = c(102, 101, 100, 107, 91, 80, 80, 68, 65, 69, 69, 74, 66, 58, 59, 64, 76, 70, 73, 71, 60),
col3 = c('Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', NA),
col4 = c(91, 70, 73, 71, 80, 80, 58, 59, 64, 68, 65, 102, 101, 100, 69, 69, 74, 66, 76, 60, NA))

col1 col2 col3 col4
Wed  102  Wed   91
Thu  101  Thu   70
Fri  100  Fri   73
Sat  107  Sat   71
Sun   91  Sun   80
Mon   80  Mon   80
Tue   80  Tue   58
Wed   68  Wed   59
Thu   65  Thu   64
Fri   69  Fri   68
Sat   69  Sat   65
Sun   74  Sun  102
Mon   66  Mon  101
Tue   58  Tue  100
Wed   59  Wed   69
Thu   64  Thu   69
Fri   76  Fri   74
Sat   70  Sat   66
Sun   73  Sun   76
Mon   71  Mon   60
Tue   60  NA    NA
```

The important part is to get the `df2` to drop the rows in `df2$col3` until it matches the weekday in `df1$col1`

Solution:
I used `cbindX` function from `gdata` package
`df3 = cbindX(df1, df2)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this in two steps:

Find the first matched entry of df2 to df1 and
 `cbind` them filling the empty entries with NA. There are a few ways to bind unequal length data frames. You can find a few [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o). I chose to use `qpcr:::cbind.na()`

```
i1 <- which(df1$col1[1] == df2$col3)[1]
qpcR:::cbind.na(df1, df2[i1:nrow(df2),])
```

which gives,

> ```
>    col1 col2 col3 col4
> 2   Wed  102  Wed   91
> 3   Thu  101  Thu   70
> 4   Fri  100  Fri   73
> 5   Sat  107  Sat   71
> 6   Sun   91  Sun   80
> 7   Mon   80  Mon   80
> 8   Tue   80  Tue   58
> 9   Wed   68  Wed   59
> 10  Thu   65  Thu   64
> 11  Fri   69  Fri   68
> 12  Sat   69  Sat   65
> 13  Sun   74  Sun  102
> 14  Mon   66  Mon  101
> 15  Tue   58  Tue  100
> 16  Wed   59  Wed   69
> 17  Thu   64  Thu   69
> 18  Fri   76  Fri   74
> 19  Sat   70  Sat   66
> 20  Sun   73  Sun   76
> 21  Mon   71  Mon   60
> 1   Tue   60 <NA>   NA
> ```

Comment: I tried these steps. it works only for this case. For exemple, if we randomly remove a date from df1 or df2, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Here is my exemple : df2 <- data.frame(col3 = c('Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun',
                           'Mon', 'Tue', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 
                           'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 
                           'Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon'),
                  col4 = c(107, 91, 70, 73, 71, 80, 80, 58, 64, 68,
                           65, 102, 101, 100, 69, 69, 74, 66, 76, 60))

Comment: Thanks, @Sotos, it worked. I have a custom function to do unequal cbind.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this :

```
library(dplyr)

new_df1 <- df1 %>% 
  mutate(row_index = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(col1,row_index) %>%
  group_by(col1) %>%
  mutate(week = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% mutate(day = paste(col1, week, sep= "_")) %>% 
  arrange(row_index)
new_df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(row_index = row_number()) %>%
  arrange(col3,row_index) %>%
  group_by(col3) %>%
  mutate(week = row_number()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% mutate(day = paste(col3, week, sep= "_")) %>% 
  arrange(row_index)

df <- new_df1 %>%
  full_join(new_df2,by = c("day" = "day")) %>% 
  select(col1, col2, col3, col4)
```

Comment: This works, but it adds several new columns to the final df which is not an ideal scenario.