# Connect two data frames by columns of different lengths and fill NA's where one dataframe falls short.?

Tags: r

I have 2 data frames D1 and D2.
dim(D1) = 6096 x 2
dim(D2) = 6100 x 5
I would like to connect D1 and D2 such that we have both the two columns of D2 followed by both the 4 columns of D2 on the right. And, 4 rows of first two columns (D1) have NA's or Null or 0 values.
I'm looking for a function.
Many questions on stacks overflow are where both data frames are added to each other either by rows or column. I don't want to add their values.

Imagine dataframes df1 and df2 and the output is dfinal.

> 

```
df1 = data.frame(rep(c(1,3,5,7), 2))
df2 = data.frame(rep(c(2,4,6,8), 2))
df1 = cbind(df1,df2)
colnames(df1) = c("C1","C2")
df3 = data.frame(rep(c("1","b","c"), 2))
df4 = data.frame(rep(c("d","3","f"), 2))
df5 = data.frame(rep(c("g","h","2"), 2))
df2 = cbind(df3,df4,df5)
colnames(df2) = c("C3","C4","C5")
df2 = rbind(df2, NA)
df2 = rbind(df2, NA)
dfinal = cbind(df1,df2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: No, that's not the solution. There are many questions that mislead to think that my and their question is the same.

Comment: What about this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o

Comment: Please illustrate with sample data that mimics your structure: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: I have uploaded the code and instructions. Thanks!