# How to create a table of 2 columns from 2 tables of a single column

Tags: r

I have two tables, each are a list of numbers like:

Table A:

```
3.5
3.4
```

Table B:

```
3.2
3.1
```

I want to make a new table like this:

```
Table C
Column A     Column B
3.5          3.2
3.4          3.1
```

When I try and add them together like:
table_c <- c(Table A, Table B) then I get the two tables added together rather than a new table of both columns.

I cannot use tibble because they are of different sizes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o

Does this not solve your issue? If not, can you provide some more detail please?

Comment: This just looks like `C <- cbind(A, B)` Have you tried that?