# Sum of columns from different data frames (different lengths) in R

Tags: r, sum

I am new to R and I have to do something as:
I have to get a final result of the following: final_x=df1+df2+df3
where df1, df2, and df3 are three data frames with 1 column each (but different lengths) as follows:

`df1`

```
      x1
1.    1
2.    4
3.    4
4.    6
```

`df2`

```
      x2
1.     1
2.     4
3.     4
4.     6
5.     6
6.     6
7.     8
```

`df3`

```
       x3
1.     1
2.     4
3.     4
4.     6
5.     6
```

As a final result, I would like my final_x to be the following:

`final_x`

```
      final
1.       3
2.      12
3.      12
4.      18
5.      12
6.      6
7.      8
```

So to get the sum of each element from the columns, despite their different lengths. Basically, when I try to sum them up, I get the error saying '+' only defined for equally-sized data frames.

Comment: You can find some really good answers  here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to cbind or rbind different lengths vectors without repeating the elements of the shorter vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3699405/how-to-cbind-or-rbind-different-lengths-vectors-without-repeating-the-elements-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is shown how we could do it:

```
#data:
df1 <- tibble(x1 = c(1,4,4,6))
df2 <- tibble(x2 = c(1,4,4,6,6,6,8))
df3 <- tibble(x3 = c(1,4,4,6,6))

# 1. construct a list
df_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

#install.packages("qpcR")
library(qpcR)

# 2. Use `cbind.na` from gpcR package to fill the lacking length with `NA`, so all columns have the same length:
df_result <- do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, df_list)

# 3. Use `rowSums` to sum
df_result$final <- rowSums(df_result, na.rm = TRUE)

# 4. save as dataframe
final_x <- data.frame(final = df_result[,4])

# 5. call result:
final_x
```

```
  final
1     3
2    12
3    12
4    18
5    12
6     6
7     8
```

Comment: Very elegant solution using qpcR package. Very useful when you work with a lot of data frames. Works great! Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution based on an [old discussion from R-help at r-project.org](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2016-December/443790.html).

This makes use of the custom base-R functions `cbind.na()` and `rbind.na()` from Andrej-Nikolai Spiess.

```
source("http://www.dr-spiess.de/scripts/cbind.na.R")
source("http://www.dr-spiess.de/scripts/rbind.na.R")

rowSums(cbind.na(df1, df2, df3), na.rm = TRUE)
#[1]  3 12 12 18 12  6  8
```

Comment: Short and works great! Thank you :)